# cocos2d-js different language Integration

Tags: arabic, cocos2d-js

Can anybody tell me how to display Arabic language fonts, arabic labels on Cocos2d Html5(cocos2d-js)?

I have tried installing Arabic fonts but it doesn't work. I haven't done this kind of stuff before. So i don't have even bit of idea. Please Help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Does it show with errors? Does the label show blank? Do you see anything in the console? Are you trying to run it in the browser or compiling?
What encoding are you saving the file in? (UTF-8?)
Could you post a code snippet of how you are attempting to use it?
Also, this may be a tricky issue, you may have better luck posting this question [at the official forums in the javascript category](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/category/javascript).

Comment: No the thing is , I don'y know the procedure and I just wanted to know the procedure as I event dont know how to stat for this..

Comment: I see.. Well, for starters, have you tried creating a `cc.LabelTTF` and trying to display arabic text in it to see what happens?